# Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated. But I am not using this method

Tags: react-native

I am developing an App that uses the navigations (Stack and TabNavigator) however, after upgrading react navigation to version 4, a deprecated "componentWillMount" error message appears. but I am not using this method anywhere in my application. What can it be?

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';


import Screen1 from './Screen1';


const telas = createStackNavigator({
  Tela1:{
    screen:Screen1
  }
})

export default createAppContainer(telas);

//------------------------------------------

import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';


import Tab1 from './Tab1';
import Tab2 from './Tab2';


const telas = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Tela1:{
    screen:Tab1
  },
  Tela2:{
     screen:Tab2
  }
})

export default telas;

//----------------------- Tabs
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class Tab1 extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Tab1</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using `AnimatedComponent`?

Comment: nop.......................

Answer (score 4):

EDITING:
You are using BottomTabNavigator.This implementation use Animated that contains this method: 'componentWillMount'. See:

[image]

For ago you might add this code in index.js:

```
import {YellowBox} from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: componentWillMount']);
```

This code will hide all warnings that started with 'Warning: componentWillMount...'

Issues about: https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-reanimated/issues/353#issuecomment-526987704.

Comment: What to do in this case? Do I need to change the component? This component is recommended.

Comment: I am updating my answer and adding a temporary solution until reanimated to be updated.

Comment: Put the YellowBox component on two tabs, but the warning is still showing.

Answer (score 1):

You might not be using that but the libraries that you use in your project might use that and the error warning might be from those libraries using those methods.

Always use the libraries which are regularly maintained and have least open issues

Comment: What to do in this case? Do I need to change the component? This component is recommended.

Comment: You need not to do anything. You can ignore the warning